# QThread and QML Locking Up

Tags: qt, qml, qthread

I have a class, audio_engine_interface, and in main.cpp, I add it to the QML thing.

```
viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("engine", engine);
```

In audio_engine_interface, I have a audio_engine class, which is computationally intensive—it needs to run on its own thread.

```
void audio_engine_interface::play()
{
    QThread thread;
    thread.start();

    engine->moveToThread(&thread);

    engine->play(); // Will use 100% of CPU
}
```

However, when I do this, the whole QML thread locks up, meaning I can't pause (pretty important). Am I missing something?

EDIT:
This thread won't mess up anything or access objects from other places. However, it does have a pause function that will need to be called at some point. For what it's worth, the engine is doing pitch shifting.

Comment: Yeah, there's a QML-specific mechanism for this. Otherwise, GUI thread is gui thread and is the only thread from which you can render. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-workerscript.html

Comment: I'm using C++, not Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, but you can invoke C++ from javascript and vice versa. So it's pretty much irrelevant what you're using.

Comment: Okay, didn't realise that. So make a function that calls engine.play(), and then do a workerscript for that function?

Comment: Simply call from a `Workscript` whatever you want to have done in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem: -

```
Qthread thread;
```

Creating a QThread object like this is creating it on the stack. When the function ends, the object will go out of scope and delete the QThread object.

You need to dynamically allocate the object on the heap: -

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
```

Then remember to delete the thread, or set it to delete itself: -

```
//Qt 5 connect syntax
connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);
```

You should also be aware of thread affinity (the thread which an object is running on). I suggest reading [this article](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) on how to use QThread properly.

Comment: I'm doing this method—though not too sure about the deleteLater, I want to reuse this thread, or at least engine. And it doesn't cause the QML to freeze when playing. However, when pausing, it does. Any pointers as to why this could be?

Comment: Ignore that. There was a lingering audio_decoder process that was causing it to hang up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted ;O)

Answer (score 1):

You have so many problems.

1. when you move to thread your object must not have a parent
2. your thread object is local variable so it will day immediately when `udio_engine_interface::play()` end execution
3. you are invoking you `engine->play();` method directly and this means that it will be executed in current thread.

`moveToThread` means that slots invked by signals connected using default 5th parameter (`Qt::AutoConnection`) will be queued in event loop of given thread.

The easiest way to fix it is use `QtConcurrent`:

```
void audio_engine_interface::play()
{
    QtConcurrent::run(engine, &EngineClass::play);
}
```

Depending what your engine does you should make it thread safe (use mutex locks an so on), without details it is hard to tell, what exactly you should do.

Comment: If I do this method, will I be able to call engine->pause()?

Comment: @MarekR, you may be interested in this thread about QtConcurrent and QFuture: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.devel/7942

Comment: I've seen it, still I would use `QtConcurrent::run` (other `QtConcurrent` have low practical value).

Comment: @user2195592 all depends on what you have underneath and how you `pause` is working. without details it hard to tell anything more.